# In Skype, can I use a camera installed on another computer?

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, skype, webcam

I have two laptops: one has a camera but it is too slow to make a video call; another if fast enough but its camera is broken.

How can I make Skype on the fast one to use the camera from the other one?

I can connect them by remote desktop or SSH.

I think local resources sharing in Remote Desktop is not a solution because I need to be on the fast one, so it should have access to the remote camera, not vice versa. Anyway, when I remote from the slow one, the camera does not appear among sharable resources,

Comment: The type of camera you have connected to your laptop cannot be accessed by another computer in such a way it can be used with Skype.

Comment: @Ramhound It's its internal camera.

Comment: Yes;  I realized that, which is the reason it cannot be accessed by another computer and used by Skype.

Comment: An internal cam is usually just a USB camera. There are quite a few tools available for sharing USB device over lan. Commercial ones are not worth it(you may just get a USB webcam then), here is a free&open source solution: http://usbip.sourceforge.net/ but I never tried it myself so I post it as a comment here.

Comment: External webcams are inexpensive. You could just buy one and be done for less than the hassle you will have trying to get this to work (if it will even work).

Comment: @Chris.C This could be the answer. However, the authors did not care to tell us how to run this software, so as it is it's a waste of time. I could not figure out how to run it. (I am on Windows 7.)